# Why are Dart's type annotations on the left?

Tags: dart, types

New languages, TypeScript, Kotlin, Scala, and Rust all have type annotations on the right, but Dart has type annotations on the left. Is this designed that way for a reason or benefit? Is there a possibility that the type annotation will be changed to the right in the future roadmap or when Dart3 is developed? I like most of Dart, but I don't like this syntax. I have looked for a thread discussing this but could not find one. Is it discussed anywhere?

Comment: Can you give an example or two of the syntax you are referring to?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I think OP means Java-like `TypeA a = ... `  syntax vs `var a  : TypeA = ...`. In any case, I am voting to close this question. Questions regarding the reasons behind language design should be directed to the maintainers through official channels, anyone else can only speculate. My speculation will be I doubt anyone will bother rewriting the parser just because some people are more used to one syntax than the other

Comment: You can put a vote on: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1499 . But it does not seem to be popular. I also very much prefer the current syntax but I do also have a background in Java and C#.

Comment: Dart came out before typescript and kotlin (and swift), so it could not have used these languages as inspiration for its type syntax. Rust was only about a year old when dart came out, and I don't think it was as popular then as it is now. Dart likely chose this syntax because languages like Java, C#, and C++ have type on the left syntax. At the time dart came out type on the right syntax would was mostly in functional languages like Scala, F#, OCaml, etc..

Comment: The syntax almost certainly was chosen for people who are already familiar with Java, C++, C, etc.  There are many more people who are familiar with those languages than with TypeScript, Kotlin, Scala, and Rust, especially at the time when Dart was created.  Much of Dart's syntax was chosen to not feel foreign to existing programmers and therefore generally avoids new idioms.  Also see [a response from Seth Ladd](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/132592/) (a Google product manager with ties to the Dart and Flutter teams) about a similar question.

Comment: Bob Nystrom, a member of the Dart language team, also [has posted some thoughts about syntax familiarty](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/g/misc/c/yKu2TFCyC1E/m/_tSs5toJKpQJ).

Comment: @jamesdlin Do you know what is the most interesting? Much of what Bob Nystrom used as a strong argument has been questioned by the Dart developers. As a result, Dart 2.0 was born. The exact opposite of what Bob Nystrom called undeniable virtues. That is, Bob Nystrom did not look into the future then and did not even try to do it. Although already then other users tried to draw the attention of developers to this, in this post. !!!!!!12 years ago!!!!!! Pattern matching, type inference, "real" static typing,  immutable types etc.

Comment: @jamesdlin What can you thank Bob Nystrom for? It is even unpleasant for me to read his arguments, but the arguments of those who did not agree with him at that time are much more pleasant and understandable. And they were 100% right, and Bob Nystrom was only partly right. And a noteworthy fact - now Bob Nystrom does everything that he then refused, well, or pretend that it is unimportant.

Comment: @mmcdon20  `Dart came out before typescript ...`. Typescript was introduced only one year later than Dart. It turns out that Microsoft had enough funds to design a language with a new (and not complicated and very convenient) syntax, and Google only lacked the desire to do this (engineering and design of a more modern syntax)? But Typescript initially (only a year after the release of Dart) was facing the future, unlike Dart. Dart developers, on the other hand, had to curtail the development of Dart 1.0, recognizing it as deprecated and posting a new Dart 2.0 that is incompatible with Dart 1.0

Comment: @mezoni neither prefix type syntax nor postfix type syntax is new or innovative. Both are copied from existing languages. The oldest language I can think of with postfix type syntax is pascal (1970), which is older than the oldest language I can think of with prefix type syntax C (1972), but I'm not certain if those languages came up with those syntaxes or even earlier language did.

Comment: @mmcdon20 I didn't mean developing something new. I meant the development of the `syntax of a new language` (that is, in fact, not a new syntax but the development of the `design of the language`). New trends show that certain well-established syntaxes in practice are no longer able to provide an opportunity to improve the design of languages. That is, they had a limit that prevents them from making improvements to the language design. The Dart developers knew this and announced these limitations when moving to Dart 2.0. But they neglected this fact. P.S. I programmed in Turbo Pascal. :-)

Answer (score 3):

The Dart syntax was inspired by Java/C#/JavaScript, which are all from the C-family of language syntax. Dart is in that family too.

Using a C-like syntax means putting types before identifiers in declarations, and using the placement to recognize what is a type and what is not. That's why you can use the same names for types and variables. (Not that you should, but the grammar doesn't care).

The goal was familiarity to users of those languages.
It was an explicit goal to be *unsurprising* to users of those languages.

Dart also has other C-syntax idiosyncrasies, like the conditional operator `?`/`:`, or the `for(..;..;..)..` loop, and ending statements with a `;`.
It's familiar, if that's the thing you are already familiar with.

Having a C-like syntax has its down-sides too, when it comes to adding new language features. Because the C syntax is so grammatically dense, there's not much room to add new syntax in the gaps. Most things already mean something, and are there for a reason (it's incredibly hard to, e.g., remove semicolons, because the grammar isn't built to be able to guess where a new statement start.)
On the other hand, it's syntactically dense too, aka "not verbose". That's usually considered a good thing.

As for odds of a large syntax change, like moving types to the right, in Dart 3.0 ... I'd say 0.0%.

It has to be an *incredibly* valuable change to outweigh having to migrate *every Dart file in existence*. Simply moving types to a another place in the code isn't going to be that by itself.
It would have to be a complete re-imagining of the entire language syntax. And should still keep supporting the old syntax forever.
(Maybe Dart 10.0 NSE - New Syntax Experience!)

Answer (score 0):

Why are Dart's type annotations on the left?
Dart (Dash) was intended to replace JavaScript.
The developers of Dart did not hesitate (unlike the developers of other modern languages) to copy most of the syntax from JavaSctipt and Java.
The main reason is to copy the syntax of popular programming languages.
Not the best, but the easiest way.
Suffice it to recall the long-standing problem with the definition of the `Function` type.

All this suggests that the developers of Dart (Dash) did not initially plan to invest in developing a new and modern syntax for the new language (unlike other developers who did not go down the simple path of copying the syntaxes of existing languages).
It can be assumed that they chose this simplest way to develop the latest programming language, since the developers were not sure that the main goal would be achieved. And, as we all know, the main goal was to create a language that would become a replacement for JavaScript.
But the miracle did not happen and Dart (Dash) never became a replacement for JavaScript.
In this case, this may partly justify why the funds were initially saved on the development of language design for something that other developers of programming languages ​​did not save on. In this case, this is giving the language a modern look and, most importantly, a practical design.

P.S.
Apparently, if something is very good to imitate and mix two (popular) into one and slightly modify it (but obligatory not to overdo it in innovations), then you can count on success only on the basis of this.

Please excuse me for the inaccuracy. The main goal was not just to replace JavaScript, but `ultimately` to replace JavaScript.

`The goal of the Dash effort is ultimately to replace JavaScript as the lingua franca of web development on the open web platform.`

Link to full text: https://gist.github.com/paulmillr/1208618

...Browser VM -- Our aspiration is that Dash will ultimately be a viable substitute for Javascript as the native client-side language of choice across all browsers.

Oh...
At the same time, at the initial stage, nothing was done to make the design of the language practical (that is, suitable for future improvement of its construction).